# Is it possible to connect QuickMapServices to Apple map satellite imagery?

Tags: qgis, quickmapservices, apple

Browsing the web I came upon https://satellites.pro/ and noticed that Apple maps has higher satellite resolution imagery than Google or Bing in some areas.  I tried QuickMapServices plugin in QGIS but Apple maps is not listed anymore.
Any idea?  Tried using satellite.pro itself but it didn't work;

e.g.

satellites.pro/Mali_map#14.357793,-2.786880,19

URL: [https://satellites.pro/Mali_map#{y},{x},{z}](https://satellites.pro/Mali_map#%7By%7D,%7Bx%7D,%7Bz%7D)

Comment: If thats the maps url you can add it as xyz tile map.

Comment: yes i tried that using url above, did not work.  suggestion?

Comment: apple uses (x,y,z) +scale +version https://cdn3.apple-mapkit.com/ti/tile?style=0&size=1&x=37202&y=51485&z=17&scale=1&lang=en&v=2010085&accessKey= accessKey= will be the developer key.

Comment: @mapperz is there any way to generate the key without enrolling in the developer program?

Comment: @user25976 unfortunately not.